# Check if handle belongs to the current process?

Tags: winapi, process, handle

Is there any Win32 API to check if a given handle belongs to the current process?

Comment: I'd like to say "any" but I get the impression that it would make it impossible or a lot harder. So I'll settle for a window handle :)

Comment: Window handles as per the current answer. Any kind of kernel handle - like a file handle? Kernel handles happen to be implemented as array indexes in a per process handle table. So they will have values like "1" or "2". Which means theres no sane way to determine which process a kernel handle belongs to :- they only make sense in the context of their own process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a window handle you can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get process id.
From a process handle you get the id with [GetProcessId Function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I don't know how easy is to get a process handle from some other handle. But I believe it'll have to do with [kernel objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485%28VS.85%29.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: Window handles aren't kernel objects. They're managed by Win32 with user32.dll in user mode.

Answer (score 1):

A handle can "belong" to more than one process (Inherited handles in child process etc)